# Found unknown operator in query: >

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am using Yii 2 and Mongo DB. Below condition throws error.

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['>', 'discount', 50]);
```

**frontend\controllers\DealController.php**

```
 $searchModel = new DealSearch();

 $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchDeals(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

**frontend\models\search\DealSearch.php**

```
public function searchDeals($params)
    {        
        $query = deal::find();        
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,          
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 3 ,                              
            ], 
        ]);

        $this->load($params);        
        if (!$this->validate()) {            
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'status' => '1',
            'approved_status' => '1',           
           //'discount >=' => $this->discount[1],
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,                       
           'state_id' => $this->state_id,
           'city_id' => $this->city_id,           
        ]);

         $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'deal_title', $this->deal_title])
                ->andFilterWhere(['>', 'discount', 50]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Found unknown operator in query: >

Comment: not sure. try  $query->andFilterWhere(['$gt', 'discount', 50]);

Comment: i already tried and still showing error:- Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
Found unknown operator in query: $GT

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: have you tried with MongoDb? I am using MongoDb for database.

Comment: I think in the class of yii\mongodb\Collection there is no condition for this.  
 class Collection extends Object
{
 public function buildCondition($condition)
    {
       
        static $builders = [
            'AND' => 'buildAndCondition',
            'OR' => 'buildOrCondition',
            'BETWEEN' => 'buildBetweenCondition',
            'NOT BETWEEN' => 'buildBetweenCondition',
            'IN' => 'buildInCondition',
            'NOT IN' => 'buildInCondition',
            'REGEX' => 'buildRegexCondition',
            'LIKE' => 'buildLikeCondition',           
        ];

Comment: No I did not try with Mongo. Will do it once get time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems, that operators like: `>`, `<`, `>=`, `=<` are not supported by `mongodb` yii extension. But you can use `between` operator directly:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'discount', 50, 400]);
```

where `400` - is some big value(related to your purposes). And the result query will be looks like this:

```
{"discount":{"$gte":50,"$lte":400}}
```

Comment: For the time being i am using this condition - $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'discount', 50, 400]); It is working fine.

Comment: Thank u very much to support me.

Comment: @MohdBashir, you are welcome. If answer is helpful - please, assept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple hash condition:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
      'discount' => ['$gt'=> 50],
    ]);
```

Comment: This code will not be work, because `{$gt: 50}` will be escaped to `"{$gt: 50}"` and in result query you will get: `{"discount":"{$gt: 50}"}` instead of `{"discount":{$gt: 50}}` - the main different in double quotes.

Comment: I tried above condition and it did not return any error but does not return any result set.

Comment: Yes, it true. No results - because query is incorrect quouted. You can enable yii debug and see mongodb logs of executed queries.

Comment: use condition like

`$query->andFilterWhere(['discount' => ['$gt' => 50]]);`